# Check if files are open (because of error: "text file busy") in Python

Tags: python, tshark

I have a big pcap file, from which I filter out some packets with tshark, save them in new pcap files and put the filenames of the new pcap files in an array called "filename_array". At the end I delete all the files which are saved in the filename_array. But one file from this array is still open when the delete process starts and due to that the error "text file busy" occurs.

So, a solution would be, to check, if all files of the array are closed. If it's true, I can delete all of them. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it expected that one file is still open??

Comment: nope! all files should be closed until the delete process starts

Comment: Is this Unix? You should be able to delete _any_ files, even busy-text-files (meaning: machine code from this file is loaded into memory, and the file is used as memory-mapped-file).

Comment: Could you post your code? It looks like you have an issue with a file not properly closed, which is going to be difficult to debug without the actual source code.

Comment: Strange ... when I execute the script in a virtual box linux on a windows computer, the above error occurs, but when I run it in an ubuntu system, the script runs flawlessly ...

Answer (score 2):

You can check for exception while reading or deleting the file and handle it.

```
try:
    with open('filename'):
        #include the file to be deleted in array
except IOError:
    # skip the file
```

Comment: This is not valid python. You need a `pass` indented below the `with`!

Comment: And what you think happens to file which is still open after this?

Comment: Skip the file. You can't delete a file which has a lock on it.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is use 'lsof' to list all opened files in system

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/lsof-command-examples

https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/linux-lsof-command